# Regular expression for Phone Numbers with different lengths

Tags: javascript, regex

I searched on Google for phone number regex validations but haven't been able to make it work based on my requirements.

Basically, I have three separate sets of rules for the prefix:

- For 10 digit numbers I need to make sure the first 3 are numbers starting from 2-9.
- For 11 digit numbers I need to make sure the first 4 are numbers starting from 1-9.
- For for anything greater than 12 digits I need to make sure the first 7 are numbers from 0-9.

After that I can allow letters like 1888GOSUPER or something like that (this would fall under the second condition)

This is what I have so far but I am not certain if I have covered everything:

```
var reg10 = /^[2-9]{3}[a-z0-9]+$/i;
var reg11 = /^[1-9]{4}[a-z0-9]+$/i;
var reg12plus = /^[0-9]{7}[a-z0-9]+$/i;
```

Comment: So `222aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa` is a valid number?

Comment: i control the length with a separate validation, unless there is a nice way to include it here in the regex?

Comment: any reason to not do it right here? How do you distinguish between which regex it matched if each of them expects different length?

Comment: yeah that i am not sure how.. :)

Comment: you have used `{3}` to check if the prefix is 3 chars long and cannot get that you can use `{7}` to check that the left part should be 7 chars long? Was it a special book that stated that regexes can only check if a string is exactly 3 chars long?

Comment: I check the length of my string

Comment: Oh thats right, did not realize until now thanks

Comment: how about `[a-z0-9]{7}` ?

Comment: yeah that helps, how about everything else .. is fine?

Comment: Yep, I think so. Personally I would use `\d` instead of `0-9` but it's just my preference

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be handled by one regex (including your check for length, as suggested by others).  Probably can be done more succinctly than this, but I feel this is more readable in the context of your 3 specifically separate prefix requirements:

`^(?:[2-9]{3}[a-z0-9]{7})$|^(?:[1-9]{4}[a-z0-9]{7})$|^(?:[0-9]{7}[a-z0-9]{5,})$`

Basically combines your three separate cases via "alternation" `|`

This can be "normalised" slightly, without "breaking" the clarity of intent, by grouping the entire expression and then surrounding with start/end anchors (rather than repeating these in each option, as above).  Although this results in a similar length rule overall, by the time we add our additional non-capturing group:

`^(?:(?:[2-9]{3}[a-z0-9]{7})|(?:[1-9]{4}[a-z0-9]{7})|(?:[0-9]{7}[a-z0-9]{5,}))$`

Comment: @user710502 My pleasure mate. Note answer updated, first rule now allows 3 prefix and 7 suffix for total of 10 digits.

Comment: @zerkms Thanks for the correction :-) Although it was _still_ wrong ;-)  I had `{9}`, you changed to `{8}`, but it should've been `{7}` (for the suffix on a ten digit number)!

Comment: The only issue i am having now its that it allows this to pass 222GoSHOwT3&&__  :(

Comment: @user710502 Updated answer, wasn't properly anchoring each alternat case.  Have included two different formats for same expression result, I'll leave it to you to decide which you like best.